# How to get packet capture in Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently working on a project involving use of AWS.

I have a setup in which there is a VPC with 3 EC2 instance running in it.
-2 Redhat serve CLI.
-1 Ubuntu server converted to GUI and     Wireshark install on it.

My question is,
I need to get the network traffic between 2 redhats To be captured on Wireshark in the ubuntu instance. 
How to to that is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**All change.**   This is now possible using VPC traffic mirroring.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-traffic-mirroring/

Originally I wrote:

It is not possible perform promiscuous mode network captures on AWS, so the Ubuntu box will never be able to view the traffic directly as you ask.

However, if you run a remote agent on ONE of the redhat machines you can have it pass the traffic that is passing between the two redhat machines to the Ubuntu box.

There's a nice writeup on using that technique here:

http://blog.nielshorn.net/2010/02/using-wireshark-with-remote-capturing/